# ¿Cómo hacer una Sentencia SQL que muestre los Clientes que tienen 3 meses sin comprar?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente sentencia SQL:

```
select date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 3 month) as '3 Meses de Diferencia', 
cliente.nombrecliente from ordencompra
inner join Articulo on Articulo.id_articulo = ordencompra.id_articulo
inner join compra on compra.id_compra = ordencompra.id_compra
inner join cliente on cliente.id_cliente = ordencompra.id_cliente
group by ordencompra.id_cliente;
```

NOTA: la función date_sub me devuelve el intervalo de tiempo con la fecha actual (pasándole 3 meses como resta), necesito saber cuales fueron los clientes que tienen 3 meses o mas sin comprar. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: usando esa funcion en el where? tu pregunta falla en muchas cosas.. que son todos esos joins? porque usas un group by que no tiene sentido? que trataste de hacer con esa consulta? podrias explicar mucho mejor cual es el resultado que queres, y cual es la entrada que tenes?

Comment: Necesito saber cuales son los clientes que tienen mas de 3 meses que no compran en la tienda, realmente estoy perdido con eso. Si usted puede realizar una sentencia que me de ese resultado con tablas que usted se invente para ilustrarlo mejor seria un éxito. Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: a ver.. si yo me invento todo, es tan simple como hacer where fechaultimacompra < date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 3 month)... ahora, sabes como calcular la fecha de ultima compra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En SQL, si te vales de la cláusula `not exists` puedes escribir la consulta casi como la expresas en lenguaje natural, por ejemplo:

```
select cliente.*
  from cliente
 where not exists (select 1
                     from OrdenCompra
                    where OrdenCompra.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente
                      and OrdenCompra.FechaCompra >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 month)
                  )
```

Esto va a excluir a todos los clientes para los que exista al menos un registro en la tabla `OrdenComnpra` que tenga el hipotético campo `FechaCompra` en los últimos 3 meses.

Por tanto, nos devuelve todos los clientes que no tengan una `OrdenCompra` en este mismo período.

Comment: Excelente, gracias amigo!